# Как выделить активную ссылку в меню другим цветом при нажатии?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Подскажите как выделить активную ссылку в меню другим цветом при нажатии? Есть меню в html на странице следующего вида:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#main_menu ul.menu_other_page li').on('click', function() {
    $('#main_menu ul.menu_other_page li a span').removeClass('parent'); //заберет актив у всех ссылок
    $(this).addClass('act'); //присвоит нужной
  });
});
```

```css
.act {
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_menu">

  <ul class="nav menu_other_page">
    <li class="item-102 parent">
      <a href=""><img src="/images/top-menu-bg-lp.png" alt=""><span class="image-title">Двери</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-103 parent">
      <a href=""><img src="/images/top-menu-bg-zk.png" alt=""><span class="image-title">Окна</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-104 current active parent">
      <a href=""><img src="/images/top-menu-bg-gp.png" alt=""><span class="image-title">Освещение</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-235 parent">
      <a href=""><img src="/images/top-menu-bg-ae.png" alt=""><span class="image-title">Мебель</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Но js код не работает, активная ссылка должна быть зеленого цвета

Comment: Можно же с помощью CSS данную задачу решить. Попробуйте дополнительный код написать с прямым изменением стиля css

Comment: Также надо проверить стиль класса, который собираемся присвоить

Answer (score 1):

Есть много способов.
Определять ссылку, передавать ссылку.. Что удобнее.

Я как-то делал вот такое:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let thisPage = location.href; // Получаем ссылку.
  thisPage = 'http://www.site.com/link3'; // Т.к. код работает в сниппете, то "эмулируем" ссылку.
  thisPage = thisPage.replace(/http:\/\/www.site.com/g, ''); // Удаляем домен, оставив только саму страницу.
  $('.nav a').each(function(){ // Пробегаем по всем ссылкам в меню
    let thisHref = $(this).attr('href'); // Получаем ссылку
    if(thisHref == thisPage) $(this).addClass('active'); // если совпадает с текущей ссылкой, то вешаем класс active
  });
});
```

```css
ul {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
li {display: inline-block; background: #ddd;}
a.active {background: green; color: white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="/link1">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/link2">Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/link3">Link 3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/link4">Link 4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/link5">Link 5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```